# React-Native Making setInterval Declarative with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm playing with React Hooks for more than a few hours, I'm probably ran into an intriguing problem: using setInterval just doesn’t work as I'd expect with react-native

```
function Counter() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
  const r = useRef(null);
  r.current = { time, setTime };
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("called");
      r.current.setTime(r.current.time + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      console.log("cleared");
      clearInterval(id);
    };
  }, [time]);

  return <Text>{time}</Text>;
}
```

The code above should clearInterval every time that `time` state changes
It works fine on `ReactJS` but on `React-native` I'm getting an error says `"Callback() it's not a function"`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4yMV.png)

It's working as expected in Reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/z69z66kjyx

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "^0.59.6",
    ...}
```

**Update:
I tried to use the ref like this example but still getting same error**

```
const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
        useInterval(() => {
            setTime(time +1);
        });

        return (<Text>{time}</Text>);
}

function useInterval(callback) {
    const savedCallback = useRef();

    // Remember the latest function.
    useEffect(() => {
        savedCallback.current = callback;
    }, [callback]);

    // Set up the interval.
    useEffect(() => {
            let id = setInterval(()=>savedCallback.current(), delay);
            return () => clearInterval(id);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are mutating the DOM via a DOM node refs and the DOM mutation will change the appearance of the DOM node between the time that's rendered and your effects mutates it. then you don't need to use `useEffect` you will want to use `useLayoutEffect`

`useLayoutEffect` this runs synchronously immediately after React has performed all the DOM mutations.

```
import React, {useState, useLayoutEffect,useRef} from 'react';
import { Text} from 'react-native';

const [time, setTime] = useState(0);
        useInterval(() => {
            setTime(time +1);
        });

        return (<Text>{time}</Text>);
}

function useInterval(callback) {
    const savedCallback = useRef();

    // Remember the latest function.
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        savedCallback.current = callback;
    }, [callback]);

    // Set up the interval.
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
            let id = setInterval(()=>{
              console.log('called');
              return savedCallback.current();
            }, delay);
            return () => {
                console.log('cleared');
                return clearInterval(id);
            }
    });
}
```

if you just using `useEffect` and getting this error

> `Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function
>       at flushFirstCallback (scheduler.development.js:348)
>       at flushWork (scheduler.development.js:441)
>       at MessagePort.channel.port1.onmessage (scheduler.development.js:188)`

This is a bug in RN because of wrong `scheduler` version, Unfortunately RN didn't have an explicit dependency on scheduler version by mistak. **Dan Abramov** already fixed this bug on scheduler version `"0.14.0"`

To solve the problem just run the following command

```
npm install scheduler@0.14.0 --save
```

Or Try adding `"scheduler": "0.14.0"` to your `package.json` in `dependencies` and re-running your package manager

Comment: Great!  I'd thought about using this other hook, but didn't have a device ready to test on so was just trying to use web simulators.  Kudos.

Comment: @DrewReese Cheers 

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to still use the state hook variables in the effect hook as they are in scope.

[useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref): mutations here aren't tracked, so they don't trigger re-renders.

[CodeSandbox Counter Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/9l42k273qr)

I feel that using refs in the way you're trying to is more verbose than just using the state and setter directly.  The `useRef` ref is intended for mutable values *over* time, but you already get that with the `useState` hook.  The ref works because you're not really mutating the ref, but instead are simply overwriting it each render cycle with the contents of the `useState` hook that *are* updated.

I've updated my sandbox to use `useRef` as the way you have, your `useEffect` hook was causing your cleanup function to fire on every render, so removed the dependency. You'll notice now you only see "called" until you refresh.

Comment: I have tried your example but I'm still getting same error, I think it's a bug in react-native, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21967

Comment: Yeah, it's been a couple years since I last did serious development in RN, but before I say that maybe refs/hooks don't work in RN I wanted to try out and verify in some online RN sandboxes, but all the ones I can find aren't updated to RN 59.  By all accounts it seems it should be working.

Comment: Yes I tried your new example the error won't show anymore, but I think `clearInterval` not trigged anymore and the `time` state not updating... maybe this will case a performance issue because setInterval calling every sec, Am I right?